# Parse Error when adding Router code to a component? (v2.0.0-beta.0)

Tags: javascript, angular

When I run the following code, I see this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://localhost:3002/angular2/router
    Error loading http://localhost:3002/public/boot.jsrun @ angular2
```

No other obvious error messages.

When I remove Router-related code from the following component, the error goes away.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {GeoSelector} from './geo-selector.component';
import {RouterOutlet, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'va-helps-app',
    templateUrl: `
        <header>
            <div class="masthead">
                <h1>{{siteTitle }}</h1>
                <h2> {{siteSubtitle }}</h2>
            </div>
            <nav class="main-navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Search </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Submit </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `,
    directives: [GeoSelector, RouterOutlet]
})


@RouteConfig([
        { path: '/home', as: 'home', component: GeoSelector }
])

export class AppComponent {
    public siteTitle = "Virginia Helps"
    public siteSubtitle = "This is what the site is for";
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to include the `router.dev.js` file into the `index.html` file of your Angular2 application:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
```

Otherwise the code you show seems correct.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: That can be the only reason. The error `Unexpected token <` refers to the first character of the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag in your 404 page (or index.html if you refer every 404 to that page) :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for this. I didn't realize the router code wasn't included angular2.dev.js. This works.